# Sorting data for NSComboBox

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nscombobox

ALL,

In my application I need to use NSComboBox. The data the combo box will display needs to be sorted.

However looking at the Apple documentation I don't see the way to make the control to have a SORT style.

Can anybody familiar with the API point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`NSComboBox` is a **view**.

You need to create a **model** or part of model that will serve as datasource for it.

If you are using array(hardcoded or getting the array from server), you can sort the array and then use them.